# How to search for word in a string (just the word)?

Tags: c#, string, cpu-word

I want to search a string for a word.

However, I don't want to get a result if the word searched is inside other word.
That is

- I want this to return the number 7 (index of letter f):

  ```
  findWord("Potato for you", "for")
  ```
- but I want this to return -1 (i.e., not found)

  ```
  findWord("Potato for you", "or")
  ```

If I use `IndexOf`, it will find the substring "or" inside the word "for".

Is there any simple way to do this?

```
char[] terminationCharacters = new char[] { '\n', '\t', ' ', '\r' };

//get array with each word to be taken into consideration
string[] words= s.Split(terminationCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int indexOfWordInArray = Array.IndexOf(words, wordToFind);
int indexOfWordInS = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= indexOfWordInArray; i++)
{
    indexOfWordInS += words[i].Length;
}
return indexOfWordInS;
```

But this obviously may not work if there are multiple spaces between the words. 
Is there any pre-built way to do this apparently simple thing, or should I just use a `Regex`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match("Potato for you", @"\bfor\b");
if (match.Success)
{
    int index = match.Index;
    ...
}
```

`\b` indicates a word boundary.

If you don't need the index but you just want to check if the word is in the string, you can use `IsMatch`, which returns a boolean, instead of `Match`.

Comment: Does that work for `"for you"` or `"Potato for"`? Just curious what the rules are for `\b`.

Comment: @krillgar, yes it does. Start or end of string is also considered a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the index, you can make a method like this. If you only want a `bool` whether or not it is in there, then the method would be a little simpler. More than likely, there could be a way to do this with a Regex easier, but they are not my forte.

I'll set it up as an extension method to make it easier to use.

```
public static int FindFullWord(this string search, string word)
{
    if (search == word || search.StartsWith(word + " "))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (search.EndsWith(" " + word))
    {
        return search.Length - word.Length;
    }
    else if (search.Contains(" " + word + " "))
    {
        return search.IndexOf(" " + word + " ") + 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```